# "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" is not working for multiple columns

Tags: mysql

Executing the query for the first time is working fine for inserting multiple column records but ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE is not working for the same records if that query is executed again. It inserts the same value again.

** First value '2' is the primary key auto-incremental  **

```
INSERT INTO info(id, docid, deptid, catid, name) 
VALUES (2,5,2,2,'John Adison')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE docid = concat(docid,',',5), deptid = concat(deptid,',',2), catid = concat(catid,',',2);
```

[image]

the output should be unchanged if it gets same records from all column.

Comment: Do you have a PRIMARY KEY or any UNIQUE KEY?

Comment: @Paul, id column is the primary key here.

Comment: The query works correctly, but is not doing what you need. So what is your question?

Comment: every single column will have unique value i.e. no duplicate value will be allowed in a record. if it sees same value is coming for a column then it will remain unchanged. insertion will work if any new value has come to concat in the records.

Answer (score -1):

if your intention is to ignore insert (dont make update) when duplicate key found then you can use `IGNORE`

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO my_table 
  ( unique_index_column, other_column ) VALUES( 1, 'other value' );
```

but this has downside that ignores all insert errors. Alternatively you can use

```
INSERT INTO table_tags (id, docid, deptid, catid, name)  VALUES (2,5,2,2,'John Adison')
   ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name=name;
```

Comment: update is working for single column but not working for multiple column when executing the query more than once.